# How to make accessor in Laravel with relations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I try to display all location on page like:

```
{{$item->country()->first()->name}}, {{$item->city()->first()->name}}, {{$item->location()->first()->name}}
```

As you can see these values from relations `country`, `city`, `location`.

How to create accessor in this case? In which model to write accessor?

I tried this:

```
public function setTeacherNameAttribute()
    {

        $this->attributes['teacher_name'] = $this->country->name;


    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. "How to create accessor in this case? In which model to write accessor?" What would this accessor do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let say your $item model called **Item** so do this in it:

```
protected $appends = ['address'];

public function getAddressAttribute(){
    $address = '';

    if (!empty($item->country())) $address .= $item->country()->first()->name;
    if (!empty($item->city())) $address .= $item->city()->first()->name;
if (!empty($item->location())) $address .= $item->location()->first()->name;
return $address;
}
```

then you can use it like this `$item->address`.

**Note:** change **address** to anything else if you already have column with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Whether using relations or just plain models, accessors are always *accessed* through the *final* model. In your case in the `country`, `city` and `location` models.

The following method creates an accessor for the `name` attribute:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value) {
  // do something with value, or not
  return $value;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand meaning of your answer. is it possible to create accessor?

Comment: Yes, just add this method to one of mentioned models. This is basically an accessor.

Comment: I dont need to use separated accessor in each models. I need to combine all in one accessor from others models/

Comment: You might be confused. Look at the docs, maybe you mean a relation, instead of an accessor.

Comment: I have relations in the same model. Now I need to return result in current model. Look at updated question

Comment: @John, Do you check my solution? note I make some edit